# BigCommerce default theme, can I edit the .less files?

Tags: css, templates, less, bigcommerce

I am trying to get a grasp of the whole BigCommerce thing.
At the moment I am trying to edit some parts of the **default theme**
At the moment the font of the default dropdown menu is Lato, I want to change that, but when I make changes to the theme.css, they get overwritten. Now, I can just put !improtant mark where I've made changes, but it's not optimal. Or I could write my css somewhere else down the html code, but It's hard to make changes to it when it's all over the place.
In the theme.css file, it says the following:

> If you edit theme.css, your changes will be overwritten by any
>   compilation of theme.less Please remember to replicate your changes in
>   init.less, or just make your changes in another file if possible

I've connected using Cyberduck to the WebDAV Server but I am unable to find any .less files. In the template folder all I can see is: Styles/theme.css

Is it even possible to edit the .less files for the default template?

Comment: You should read: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/themes/style-editor. Your Less files should be in the `Styles/less` folder. Possible only the compiled CSS has been uploaded and not your `.less` files? (which should mean also your style-editor won't work)